# Returning a string or a string reference using eval modifier

Tags: perl

Is there any advantage of returning a reference to the string instead of the string itself when using the `e` modifier?

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str1 = my $str2 = "aa bb cc";

$str1 =~ s/\s(bb)\s/${func1($1)}/e;
$str2 =~ s/\s(bb)\s/func2($1)/e;

sub func1 {
    my ($name) = @_;

    my $str = "A large string";
    return \$str;
}

sub func2 {
    my ($name) = @_;

    my $str = "A large string";
    return $str;
}
```

I am thinking about the case when the returned string is quite large. Will it be more efficient to use a reference?

Comment: It seems to me that without reference you are within the error of measurment faster (1-3% on my machine). Thus you're probably just taking up additional space for the extra reference construction (which also is negligibly small).

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. That is interesting.. it would be interesting to know why there is no string copying going on .. (for the case when I do not return a reference)

Comment: Because you are returning a perl scalar, which is already a struct (internally there's many magic happening). Perl strings are not zero delimited c-strings, you are just putting that struct on the stack.

Comment: no, there is copying going on, it just happens in both cases at different points; I'm not entirely clear on why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only benchmarking will tell, but it looks like it.

Returning a scalar usually copies it.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   sub f { my $x = 'abc'; Dump($x); $x }  Dump(f());
' 2>&1 | grep -Po 'PV = \K\S*'
0x275d5f0
0x276e270
```

But not when `:lvalue` is used.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   sub f :lvalue { my $x = 'abc'; Dump($x); $x }  Dump(f());
' 2>&1 | grep -Po 'PV = \K\S*'
0x220bd00
0x220bd00
```

5.20 introduced copy-on-write strings, so both scalars (`$x` and the returned one) share the same string buffer until you change one (forcing a copy then).

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   sub f { my $x = 'abc'; Dump($x); $x }  Dump(f());
' 2>&1 | grep -Po 'PV = \K\S*'
0xda4780
0xda4780
```

Comment: There's also an optimization concerning TEMP (mortal) scalars returned by XS functions, where the string buffer is stolen rather than copied.